# It seems like he has asked her vs. He seems to have asked her

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Which one is correct? And if both are, then please explain to me in which situations can I use "seems to have" and what is  the grammar term for it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.

> It seems like he asked her.

This is a comment on the situation as a whole ("it").

"What's going on? Can we go?"

-- "Well, it seems like he asked her, but I'm not sure *what's happening*."

> He seems to have asked her.

This is a comment on the "he".

"What's going on? Can Harry come?"

-- "He seems to have asked her, but I'm not sure *if he can come*."

The primary difference between these sentences is that the first sentence is about *it*, whereas the second sentence is about *he*. Both are correct; it just depends on what the speaker is emphasizing.